# reusing blowfish algorithm to implement bcrypt

Tags: bcrypt, blowfish

I'm trying to implement bcrypt and have a really fast Blowfish implementation available to me. It seems to me that the existant Blowfish implementation is not going to be able to be leveraged to implement bcrypt since the bcrypt key expansion kinda interleaves the salt and key together whereas Blowfish's key expansion doesn't make use of a salt or anything like a salt.

Is that a correct assumption or is there, in fact, a way to leverage an existant Blowfish implementation that I'm just not seeing?